# Woocommerce Create custom product type with variations

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic, variables

I have a plugin of booking that create a new product type of WC_Product. I'll like to change this booking product type for variable booking product type (new product type of WC_Product_Variation or WC_Product_Variable), but have somenthings errors when change this product type to variable.

How

[image]

Comment: Please ask this question in WooCommerce support, [here](https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/woocommerce) or [here](https://woocommerce.com/). WPSE is better suitable for WordPress development related question.

Comment: OK. Sorry for this

Comment: That's OK, nothing to be sorry about. Also, you're very welcome here when you have a WordPress question :)